# seleccionar elementos unicos con la misma clase

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo la pagina siguiente, el cual agrega tareas en una tabla en un tr, tiene la opcion con un checkbox de marcarlas como completas y al hacerlo le da unos estilos, tengo las opciones ver todas(all), las activas(active) y las completas(completed) para ver las tareas que cumplan con esas opciones, en all y actives ya las muestras, muestra todas y las que estan activas lo hice por su clase, al tener el checkbox activo le agrego la clase complete, y esas les doy un display none para ocultar en las activas, lo mismo en todas le quito el display none y uso el block, el problema es que en la opcion de completed, no encuentro la forma de como mostrar solo las que ya estan completas o tienen el checkbox como checked, intente selecccionar por su clase lista, pero me quita todas y por la clase complete pero me paso lo mismo.

Otra cosa es al momento de agregar y borrar con la X, pasa que me borra siempre la primer fila y no la fila que esta en la X.

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="content-header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>Todo</h1>
                </div>
            

                <div class="night">
                    <img src="images/icon-moon.svg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>  
        
        <div class="buscador">
            <div class="seeker-results">
                <div class="seeker">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                    <input type="text"  id="text" placeholder="Create a new todo...">
                </div>

                <div id="resultados">
                    <table id="results" class="results"> 

                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="options">
                    <a href="#" id="all">All</a>
                    <a href="#" id="active">Active</a>
                    <a href="#" id="completed">Completed</a>
                </div>

                <div class="footer">
                    <p>Drag and drop to rearder list</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #e4e5f1;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(../images/bg-mobile-light.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

header {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

header .content-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

header .content-header .logo h1 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

header .content-header .night img {
  width: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}



.results {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.results tr.lista {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacde8;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.results .lista .checkbox {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.results .lista .checkbox:checked {
  background: #56ddff;
  background: linear-gradient(176deg, #56ddff 0%, #bf58f3 100%);
}

.results .lista .value {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #393a4c;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #e4e5f1;
  background: #e4e5f1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.imagen {
  background-image: url(../images/icon-check.svg);
}

.results .lista td span img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  background: white;
  background: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

lista.complete {
  background: red;
}


let input = document.querySelector('#text');
let resultados = document.querySelector('#results')
let all = document.querySelector('#all');
let active = document.querySelector('#active');
let completed = document.querySelector('#completed');

all.addEventListener('click',todas);
active.addEventListener('click', activas);
completed.addEventListener('click', completas);

input.addEventListener('keypress', datosInput);


function datosInput(e){
    teclaEnter = event.keyCode;

    if(teclaEnter == 13){
        let table = document.createElement('tr');
        table.classList.add('lista');
        table.id = 'lista';

        table.innerHTML = `
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkboxDos" onChange="completo(this)"> </td>
            <td class="value">${input.value}</td>
            <td  onClick="borrar()" ><span class="borrar"><img src="../images/icon-cross.svg"></span></td>
        `
        resultados.appendChild(table);

        input.value = '';
    }
}

function borrar(e){
    let borrar = document.querySelector('.borrar');
    borrar.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

function completo(e){
    e.parentElement.parentNode.classList.toggle('complete');
}

function todas(){
    let tareasCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.complete');

    tareasCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'block'
        elem.classList.add('lista')
    });

}

function activas(){
    let tareasCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.complete');

    tareasCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'none'
        elem.classList.remove('lista')
    });
}

function completas(){
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con respecto a borrar falla porque estas pidiendo el primer elemento con la clase .borrar:

```
function borrar(e){
    let borrar = document.querySelector('.borrar');
    borrar.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

mandale el elemento por parametro

```
borrar(this)
```

y en la funcion manda a eliminar es el elemento que se esta seleccionando:

```
function borrar(e){
    e.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

asi deberia funcionar.

Con respecto a listar las completadas viendo como diseNaste tu algoritmo noto que no tienes una clase para las "no completadas" te recomiendo inicializar tus elementos no solo con la clase "lista" sino tambien con una que sea por ejemplo "noComplete"

```
table.classList.add('lista');
table.classList.add('noComplete');
```

Ahora podras representar tus dos estados (completado y no completado), para manejarlo sencillamente te recomiendo:

```
function completo(e){
    e.parentElement.parentNode.classList.toggle('complete');
    e.parentElement.parentNode.classList.toggle('noComplete');
}
```

y para visualizarlo:

```
function todas(){
    let tareasCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.complete');
    let tareasNoCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.noComplete');

    tareasCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'block'
        elem.classList.add('lista')
    });
    tareasNoCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'block'
        elem.classList.add('lista')
    });

}

function activas(){
    let tareasCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.complete');
    let tareasNoCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.noComplete');

    tareasCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'none'
        elem.classList.remove('lista')
    });

    tareasNoCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'block'
        elem.classList.add('lista')
    });
}

function completas(){
    let tareasCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.complete');
    let tareasNoCompletas = document.querySelectorAll('.noComplete');

    tareasCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'block'
        elem.classList.add('lista')
    });

    tareasNoCompletas.forEach(elem => {
        elem.style.display = 'none'
        elem.classList.remove('lista')
    });
}
```